# Are any extended ASCII or Unicode characters safe to use in console regardless of font settings?

Tags: .net, character-encoding, console, special-characters

I know that I can set the encoding in a .net console app but many Unicode and/or extended ASCII require the user be set to a true type font like consolas or that they have a specific code page set.

Other than "base" alphanumeric characters, is there a set of characters that I can reliably use regardless of the Windows console font or user-assigned code set?

**EDIT:** In my situation I need only to display latin "base ASCII" latin characters and line art. My issue is that I am unsure if I can depend upon such characters regardless of the console font or the code-page. I know there are certain things I can set from within the console application but I don't know the extent to which they depend upon or can override user settings.

Comment: This kind of question rarely has a happy answer.  But you can generally rely on the default code page for the console to support the glyphs in the language of the user.  Which thus will work fine as long as you properly localized your program.  So changing the code page is exactly what you *don't* want to do.

Comment: @HansPassant I know it's an ugly issue. In my case I only want to use "standard" latin characters plus line art. Specifically, it's only for people in the US... but I cannot rely upon what their console settings might be... only whether or not I can change them

Comment: US machines always run in 437.  You can rely on that.

Comment: @HansPassant so does that mean that I can depend on any character in the standard code pade for 437 regardless of console font settings and expect the same result? Other questions on the subject do not indicate this.

Comment: No user ever has a reason to select a non-standard font.  Surely you've been reading questions from programmers that wanted to make them do that, not from users.

Comment: @HansPassant I think what you're telling me is that I should usually be able to rely upon users in the US using a standard font and that all extended ASCII in 437 should work... is that correct? If so, convert your comment to an answer, please.